# Screen and xclip - configuration that don't work

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, x-server

I'm trying to configure GNU/Screen utility to work with X clipboard. I followed the tutorial: http://www.lowlevelmanager.com/2012/10/screen-clipboard-to-x11-clipboard.html but without a result, so I decided to modyfi the configuration to use xclip rather than xsel - just because the orginal idea didn't work for me. This is my .screen config file:

```
bind > eval writebuf "exec sh -c 'xclip -i /tmp/screen-exchange'"
bind < eval "exec sh -c 'xclip -o >/tmp/screen-exchange'" readbuf
```

The pasting work but coping the screen clipboard to X clipboard doesn't. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? I'm using: urxvt terminale emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing a <

`bind > eval writebuf "exec sh -c 'xclip -i < /tmp/screen-exchange'"`